# iOS simulator not loading older versions of OS

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have followed different posts on how to run older iOS versions on my simulator, but am still having problems getting the older OS's to actually load in the simulator.

I downloaded the OS6 simulator in XCode.

In my simulator, I have choices for OS6 and OS7.x under Hardware > Device. When I choose OS6 and run my app, the simulator changes it to OS7 and then runs it. If I change it while the app is running, the simulator/app crashes (sort of expected this). My app is set to have a minimum deployment target of iOS6.0.

I've not been able to find a way to tell XCode which version to run in the simulator.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Don't have Xcode here, but IIRC there is an option when you select the simulator under Xcode to pick which one, and included in the list is a "more options" line.  Go to that and it leads you through downloading  other simulator versions.

Comment: You don't make the choice in the simulator. You make the choice in Xcode when you choose to build and run your app. Assuming your project target has a Deployment Target of iOS 6.x, when you build and run you choose which device or which simulated device and iOS version.

Comment: Working from memory again:  To the right of the Xcode "Run" button is a kind of funny oblong button.  Click on the left end and it lets you pick which specific thing you're going to run.  Click on the right end and you get to select which device or simulator to run on.  (This "user interface" is very poorly designed and non-intuitive.)

Comment: Which version of X-Code are you using?
This will help people answer your question.

Comment: What is your target iOS for the project?